# Getting assemblies with classname "Entity" from build folder

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to get the Assemblies containing in the classname Entity. For example, ProductEntity should be in the returned assembly

Currently, I am getting all the assemblies from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();`
I filter those with a link and after that, I am trying to get the Class name with 
`Assembly.GetType().Name` This returns me an array with "runtimeAssembly" in it and nothing else.

```
var assemblyFromClass = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                               from type in asm.GetTypes()
                               where type.IsClass && type.Name.Contains("Entity") &&
                                      asm.ManifestModule.Name != "<In Memory Module>"
                                          && !asm.FullName.StartsWith("System")
                                          && !asm.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft")
                                          && asm.Location.IndexOf("App_Web") == -1
                                          && asm.Location.IndexOf("App_global") == -1
                                          && asm.FullName.IndexOf("CppCodeProvider") == -1
                                          && asm.FullName.IndexOf("WebMatrix") == -1
                                          && asm.FullName.IndexOf("SMDiagnostics") == -1
                                          && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(asm.Location)
                               select asm.GetType().FullName).ToList();
```

https://gyazo.com/e8687c49073ac3f46e0def8e927cc314

This is what I get back. I'm expecting ProductEntity, BlablaEntity
Etc

Comment: You should do `select type.FullName`

Comment: Same result @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya you where right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var assemblyFromClass  = (from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
               from type in asm.GetTypes()
               where type.Name.Contains("Entity") &&
                     asm.ManifestModule.Name != "<In Memory Module>"
                     && !asm.FullName.StartsWith("System")
                     && !asm.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft")
                     && asm.Location.IndexOf("App_Web") == -1
                     && asm.Location.IndexOf("App_global") == -1
                     && asm.FullName.IndexOf("CppCodeProvider") == -1
                     && asm.FullName.IndexOf("WebMatrix") == -1
                     && asm.FullName.IndexOf("SMDiagnostics") == -1
                     && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(asm.Location)
               select type.Name).ToList();
```